# JavaScript knocked out my webpage's static background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Edit: HTML I'm currently using for index.html = https://pastebin.com/embed_js/8Lisq2jH

I used https://html5up.net/overflow as a template for my site.
It includes the JavaScript file called "jquery.scrolly.min.js", which is altering my css directions.
I know this because when I delete that file... the background is static,
 which is what I want ("static" = background is always in same position).

Problem is, the .js file above also does other things that I need, so I can't delete it.
Below, I'll include first the .js file and then the css code for the background.

JavaScript forcing background to scroll (non-static):

```
(function(e) {
    function u(s, o) {
        var u, a, f;
        if ((u = e(s))[t] == 0) return n;
        a = u[i]()[r];
        switch (o.anchor) {
            case "middle":
                f = a - (e(window).height() - u.outerHeight()) / 2;
                break;
            default:
            case r:
                f = Math.max(a, 0)
        }
        return typeof o[i] == "function" ? f -= o[i]() : f -= o[i], f
    }
    var t = "length",
        n = null,
        r = "top",
        i = "offset",
        s = "click.scrolly",
        o = e(window);
    e.fn.scrolly = function(i) {
        var o, a, f, l, c = e(this);
        if (this[t] == 0) return c;
        if (this[t] > 1) {
            for (o = 0; o < this[t]; o++) e(this[o]).scrolly(i);
            return c
        }
        l = n, f = c.attr("href");
        if (f.charAt(0) != "#" || f[t] < 2) return c;
        a = jQuery.extend({
                anchor: r,
                easing: "swing",
                offset: 0,
                parent: e("body,html"),
                pollOnce: !1,
                speed: 1e3
            },
            i), a.pollOnce && (l = u(f, a)), c.off(s).on(s, function(e) {
            var t = l !== n ? l : u(f, a);
            t !== n && (e.preventDefault(), a.parent.stop().animate({
                scrollTop: t
            }, a.speed, a.easing))
        })
    }
})(jQuery);
```

CSS rules defining static background:

```
background-color: #2e2e2e;
background-image: url("images/overlay.png");
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
background-position: center, center;
```

If you could help me maintain the css and the rest of the .js functionality, I'd be very grateful. The site is a photo gallery dedication to my dad. I'm a beginner and feel like this is above my pay grade.

Thank you!

Comment: We're going to need to see more than a minified js file. The index file in html5up-overflow.zip has a fixed background, so there must be something else going on in your code.

Comment: I'm unsure of what to post. Basically, everything in that .zip is what I'm using. I don't mind reverting to the stock .css completely. I mainly edited html.

Comment: Here's a link to the HTML. First time using pastebin: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/8Lisq2jH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: After seeing your HTML, the JS is changing the background-position on scroll. You can add `!important` to the position in your CSS and that should work. Also, you need to remove `<!-- HEADER -->` at the top of your document. The first thing should be the `DOCTYPE` statement.

Also, your CSS is malformed, you don't need commas in attachment or position. And you only need one `fixed`, not two. You probably can also change your `background-size` to `cover` instead of `100% 100%`.

```
background-color: #2e2e2e;
background-image: url("images/overlay.png");
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-attachment: fixed !important;
background-position: center center !important;
```

There is also this in your CSS:

```
body.is-scroll {
            background-attachment: scroll, scroll;
            background-size: auto, 100% auto;
        }
```

You can change the `scrolls` to `fixed` and the background-size to `100% 100%` or `cover`

Edit: the point of the new comment by Bobby Speirs, HTML and some more info would be helpful in the event the above doesn't fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your solution. Still scrolls.

Comment: OK. Then we'll need to see some HTML and I can hopefully update this answer.

Comment: https://html5up.net/overflow <-- the html in that .zip file is what I'm using (the index.html)

Comment: You need to post a minimal example to recreate the problem, not link us to the zip file: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You also posted that you edited the HTML in your comment above.

Comment: The reason I linked the original is that this .html will be rather long. If that's OK with you, I'll update the OP with my full .html ... based upon the MCVE, the "minimum" is still a lot. Up to you

Comment: At the minimum, at least let us know what you changed. Not trying to be hard on you or anything, the more information the better :)

Comment: Heya, here's a pastebin of my HTML. I'll update the OP. I hope it's enough to determine the issue. -- https://pastebin.com/embed_js/8Lisq2jH

Comment: I think I got what you need now that I saw your HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your help!